# epoll: Distinguishing "listener" FDs

Tags: c, linux, epoll

How can I distinguish between "listener" file descriptors and "client" file descriptors?

Here's what I saw in the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/4/epoll) example:

```
if(events[n].data.fd == listener) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

'But what if I don't have access to `listener`?

Sorry if this is a vague question. I'm not quite sure how to word it.

Comment: Check the libevent - http://monkey.org/~provos/libevent/ - make sure you do not reinvent a wheel.

Comment: Yes, libevent! State machines rule!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are writing a server, you should either keep the listening socket descriptor around in some variable (`listener` in the manual page), or setup a small structure for each socket you give to `epoll_ctl(2)` and point to it with `data.ptr` member of the `struct epoll_event` (don't forget to de-allocate that structure when socket is closed).

Something like this:

```
struct socket_ctl
{
    int fd;    /* socket descriptor */
    int flags; /* my info about the socket, say (flags&1) != 0 means server */
    /* whatever else you want to have here, like pointers to buffers, etc. */
};
...
struct socket_ctl* pctl = malloc( sizeof( struct socket_ctl ));
/* check for NULL */
pctl->fd = fd;
pctl->flags = 1; /* or better some enum or define */
struct epoll_event ev;
ev.events = EPOLLIN|...;
ev.data.ptr = pctl;
...
if (( events[n].data.ptr->flags & 1 ) != 0 )
{
    /* this is server socket */
}
```

As you can see it's much more work then just having access to the server socket descriptor, but it has a nice property of keeping all information related to one socket in one place.

Comment: This way one can also associate a call-back function(s) with the file descriptor.

Comment: Yep, it's kind of ... oh the horror ... object-oriented :)

Comment: Surely you can fit a `goto` in there, somewhere! +1, I also use small structures (with *gasp* logging callbacks).

Comment: This is what I had in mind as well, but wanted a simpler solution. It'll be even more complicated, since I was going to have a separate structure for client sessions (holding more than just the fd and flags)! Feels wrong. Anyway, thanks for the help. Tick :)